# Cerioli's modified test of indepence with spatial data

Tags: r, spatial, contingency-tables, geostatistics

I have to two datasets $X$ and $Y$ with binary observations on a regular grid. A regular contingency test for independence would be flawed by the presence of spatial autocorrelation. [Cerioli (1997)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2533962) proposed a correction of the test statistic $W$ as

$$W = \frac{W}{1 + \hat{\lambda}}_n$$

where $\hat{\lambda}_n$ is derived either from the normalised product of autocovariances of $X$ and $Y$, or alternatively from the normalised product of Moran's $I$ for $X$ and $Y$.

Is anyone aware of a useable implementation of this correction in R?